# Ошибка клиента Guzzle

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram, guzzle

[image: Ошибка]

Ошибка при компиляции, клиент Guzzle выдаёт ошибку.
Помогите, пожалуйста, если можно просто описав, заранее спасибо!

Код файла TelegramBot.php

```
    `<?php

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class TelegramBot
{
    protected $token = "780497242:AAEEnEQWmhOOjTbSczGACR65GaU7Kc5D0n0";

    protected function query($method, $params = [])
    {
        $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot";
        $url .=$this->token;
        $url .="/" . $method;

        if(!empty($params))
        {
            $url .="?" . http_build_query($params);
        }

        $client = new Client(['base_url' => $url ]);

        $result = $client->request('GET');

        return json_decode(($result->getBody()));
    }
    public function getUpdates()
    {
        $response = $this->query('getUpdates');

        return $response->result;
    }

    public function sendMessage()
    {

           }
          }?>`
```

init.php

```
   <?php
    include('vendor/autoload.php');
    include('TelegramBot.php');
    //get message
    $telegramApi = new TelegramBot();
    $updates = $telegramApi->getUpdates();
    print_r($updates);
    //
    //
    ?>
```

Comment: У вас проблема не с Guzzle, а CURLом. Англоязычный SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722822/guzzle-returns-curl-error-3-url-malformed

Comment: @ArchDemon опишите, пожалуйста, я не силен в английском(

Comment: Проблема с сертификатами SSL, точнее их отсутствие. Можно выключить проверку, но там написано, что так делать не следует. В Guzzle можно подключить файл с сертификатами. Читайте мануалы

Comment: @ArchDemon спасибо буду искать